# NoSuchMethodError for com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessage.newBuilderForType on Spanner Java Client

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

Get this error while trying to experiment on google's cloud spanner by running the sample code

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/spanner/cloud-client/src/main/java/com/example/spanner/SpannerSample.java

The stacktrace is as follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessage.newBuilderForType(Lcom/google/protobuf/AbstractMessage$BuilderParent;)Lcom/google/protobuf/Message$Builder;
at com.google.protobuf.SingleFieldBuilderV3.getBuilder(SingleFieldBuilderV3.java:142)
at com.google.spanner.v1.Mutation$Builder.getInsertBuilder(Mutation.java:3227)
at com.google.cloud.spanner.Mutation.toProto(Mutation.java:377)
at com.google.cloud.spanner.SpannerImpl$TransactionContextImpl.commit(SpannerImpl.java:1223)
at com.google.cloud.spanner.SpannerImpl$TransactionRunnerImpl.run(SpannerImpl.java:1148)
at com.google.cloud.spanner.SpannerImpl$SessionImpl.write(SpannerImpl.java:704)
at com.google.cloud.spanner.SessionPool$PooledSession.write(SessionPool.java:201)
at com.google.cloud.spanner.DatabaseClientImpl.write(DatabaseClientImpl.java:31)
at spanner_test.SpannerSample.writeExampleData(SpannerSample.java:164)
at spanner_test.SpannerSample.run(SpannerSample.java:423)
at spanner_test.SpannerSample.main(SpannerSample.java:501)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

I am using gradle and my dependency is as follows:

spanner:

```
com.google.cloud:google-cloud-spanner:0.9.4-beta'
```

protobuf:

```
com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.1.0
```

Comment: I tried using this combination and it worked for me. The method for which you are getting the error has been in protobuf since version 3.0.0 so I am not sure why you are getting the error. Is it possible that somehow there are two version of protobuf on your classpath?

Answer (score 1):

The project has been migrated to a different repository [java-spanner](https://github.com/googleapis/java-spanner) and currently on the version `6.36.0` and using `protobuf-java@3.21.10`. I tried your sample [writeExampleData](https://github.com/googleapis/java-spanner/blob/main/samples/snippets/src/main/java/com/example/spanner/SpannerSample.java#L364) with the latest version and did not face the same issue.